# jQuery, increment id number when dynamically appending elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'am debutante in javascript and   I tried to provide an automatic generation mechanism of id but it doesn't work. Can you help me? 
This is my datascource:

```
var datascource = {
   'id':'1' ,'name': 'Lao Lao',
  'title': 'general manager',
  'children': [
    {  'id':'2','name': 'Bo Miao', 'title': 'department manager', 'className': 'middle-level',
      'children': [
        { 'id':'3','name': 'Li Jing', 'title': 'senior engineer', 'className': 'product-dept' },
        { 'id':'4','name': 'Li Xin', 'title': 'senior engineer', 'className': 'product-dept',
          'children': [
            { 'id':'5','name': 'Ta Ta', 'title': 'engineer', 'className': 'pipeline1' },
            { 'id':'6','name': 'Fei Fei', 'title': 'engineer', 'className': 'pipeline1' },
            { 'id':'7','name': 'Xuan Xuan', 'title': 'engineer', 'className': 'pipeline1' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    { 'id':'8','name': 'Su Miao', 'title': 'department manager', 'className': 'middle-level',
      'children': [
        { 'id':'9','name': 'Pang Pang', 'title': 'senior engineer', 'className': 'rd-dept' },
        { 'id':'10','name': 'Hei Hei', 'title': 'senior engineer', 'className': 'rd-dept',
          'children': [
            { 'id':'11','name': 'Xiang Xiang', 'title': 'UE engineer', 'className': 'frontend1' },
            {'id':'12', 'name': 'Dan Dan', 'title': 'engineer', 'className': 'frontend1' },
            { 'id':'13','name': 'Zai Zai', 'title': 'engineer', 'className': 'frontend1' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

this is my function used for adding node:

```
$('#btn-add-input').on('click', function() {
  $('#new-nodelist').append('<li ><input type="text" class="new-node"></li>');
});

$('#btn-remove-input').on('click', function() {
  var inputs = $('#new-nodelist').children('li');
  if (inputs.length > 1) {
    inputs.last().remove();
  }
});

$('#btn-add-nodes').on('click', function() {
  var $chartContainer = $('#chart-container');
  var nodeVals = [];
  $('#new-nodelist').find('.new-node').each(function(index, item) {
    var validVal = item.value.trim();
    if (validVal.length) {
      nodeVals.push(validVal);
    }
  });
```

this is my function to generate an id to each element added:

```
(function(){
var counter = 13; ( the last id in the datascource)
window.uniqueId = function(){
return counter++
}
});

$('.new-node').each(function (i, e) {
var name = uniqueId();
$(e).find(':input').each(function (j, f) {
var id = uniqueId();
$(f).attr('name', name)
.attr('id', id)
.next()
.attr('title', title);
})
});
```

There are several problem in my current code. Can you help me ?

Comment: can you past your code problems

Comment: Put all your code in a jsfiddle.net and we can try to fix it.

Comment: You haven't even told us what your program requirements are or what part of your function is not working...

Comment: you are doing wrong in defining **uniqueId** function, because you are not executing the self invoking function correctly. following is the corrected version.

    (function () {
        var counter = 13;
        window.uniqueId = function () {
            return counter++;
        };
    })();

Answer (score 0):

For the part of your problem that was **"how do I find the highest ID in a JSON-object"**

I solved it with the use of a closure

```
var getHighestID = function () {
    var highestID = 0;
    function searchID(jsonObj){
      for (var key in jsonObj) {
        if (jsonObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          if(jsonObj[key] !== null && typeof jsonObj[key] === 'object'){
            searchID(jsonObj[key]);
          }else{
            if(key == "id"){
              if(parseInt(jsonObj[key]) > parseInt(highestID)){
                highestID = parseInt(jsonObj[key]);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return {
      calculate: function(jsonObj) {
        searchID(jsonObj);
      },
      value: function() {
        return highestID;
      }
    }  
};
```

Then you just create the object and ask it to find highest ID.

```
var highestID = getHighestID();
highestID.calculate(datascource);
var currentHighestID = highestID.value();
```

If this has to be done multiple times and since you remove rows. You should add an reset() function as well.

Here's an [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Sprazer/g5hLo0bo/)

Comment: I tried the method of Highest ID but I did not assign this node id recovered added it still gives the same erro

Comment: @sasa I can't understand your direct problem, you have to narrow down the problem to something more specific. 

The method mentioned above is just to find the current highest ID in the JSON-object. 

If you have to add a new id you should check "what's the current highest ID and increment" then replace the JSON-object with a new.

Comment: that's what I did but I do not know why not afonctionne and the  added id  is not assigned to the node https://jsfiddle.net/g5hLo0bo/8/

Comment: added some comments in this fiddle, hope that can help you out
https://jsfiddle.net/Sprazer/g5hLo0bo/10/

Comment: thanks for you help ! i find the current highest id but it c'ant be assogne to the node  https://jsfiddle.net/g5hLo0bo/12/